# reactor.registerWxApp(App) giving Attribute error 'SelectReactor' object has no attribute 'registerWxApp'

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, twisted, twisted.internet

I am currently getting the error:

```
reactor.registerWxApp(app)
AttributeError: 'SelectReactor' object has no attribute 'registerWxApp'
```

I can't seem to add the app to the reactor since registerWxApp is not being recognized?  Also if i don't catch the wxreactor it raises the error that wxreactor is already installed.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import wx
    from twisted.internet import wxreactor
    try:
        wxreactor.install()
    except:
        print('already installed')
    # import t.i.reactor only after installing wxreactor:
    from twisted.internet import reactor


STREAM_URL = url

print(STREAM_URL)

factory = WebSocketClientFactory(STREAM_URL)
factory.protocol = MyClientProtocol

print('hello')

print('hi')


app = wx.App(False)
app._factory = factory
app._frame= testapi(None)
app._frame.Show()
reactor.registerWxApp(app)
print(reactor)
reactor.run()

app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made an assumption here:

```
from twisted.internet import wxreactor
try:
    wxreactor.install()
except:
    print('already installed')
```

The assumption is that the *only* reason `wxreactor.install()` could raise an exception is that wxreactor is already installed.  I expect the assumption is invalid.

Try to avoid writing `except:` in your Python programs unless you plan to include a bare `raise` in the block to re-raise whatever exception you're handling (and even so, consider using `finally` for this instead).

When you catch *all* exceptions you risk catching exceptions your code can't *actually* handle correctly.  In this case, perhaps there is some other problem installing wxreactor.  If so, then you're probably getting the default reactor when code proceeds to import `twisted.internet.reactor` after this attempt.

The exception you reported:

```
AttributeError: 'SelectReactor' object has no attribute 'registerWxApp'
```

means you do not have wxreactor installed.  You have `SelectReactor` installed.  You cannot register a wx app with select reactor.

You need to diagnose the cause of `wxreactor.install()` failing and you cannot do that by squashing and ignoring all exceptions from that call.

Comment: Thank you!  you were right.  I was not calling the correct reactor in my main.